# load multiple csv files into Dataframe: columns names issue

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, csv

I have multiple csv files with the same format (14 rows 4 columns).
I tried to load all of them into a single dataFrame, and use file's name to rename the values of the first column (1-14)

```
    1   500 0   0
    2   350 0   1
    3   500 1   0
    .............
    13  600 0   0
    14  800 0   0
```

I tried the following code but I am not getting what I am expecting:

```
    filenames = os.listdir('Threshold/')
    Y = pd.DataFrame () #empty df
    # file name are in the following foramt "subx_ICA_thre.csv"
    # need to get x (subject number to be used later for renaming columns values)
    Sub_list=[]
    for filename in filenames:
    s= int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, filename)))
    Sub_list.append(int(s))
    S_Sub_list= sorted(Sub_list) 

    for x in S_Sub_list: # get the file according to the subject number
    temp = pd.read_csv('sub' +str(x)+'_ICA_thre.csv' )
    df = pd.concat([Y, temp])  # concat the obtained frame with the empty frame
    df.columns = ['id', 'data', 'isEB', 'isEM']
    #  replace the column values using subject id
         for sub in range(1,15):
           df['id'].replace(sub, 'sub' +str(x)+'_ICA_'+str(sub) ,inplace=True)
    print (df)
```

output:

```
                id  data  isEB  isEM
   0    sub1_ICA_2   200     0     0
   1    sub1_ICA_3   275     0     0
   2    sub1_ICA_4   500     1     0
   ................................
   11  sub1_ICA_13   275     0     0
   12  sub1_ICA_14   300     0     0
                id  data  isEB  isEM
   0    sub2_ICA_2   275     0     0
   1    sub2_ICA_3   500     0     0
   2    sub2_ICA_4   400     0     0
   .................................
   11  sub2_ICA_13   300     0     0
   12  sub2_ICA_14   450     0     0
```

First, it seems that the code makes different dataFrame not a single one.Second,  the first row is removed (sub1_ICA_1 is missing, may be replaced with column names).
I couldn't find the problem in the loop that I am using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need create list of `DataFrame`s first, then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with parameter `keys` for new values by `range` in `MultiIndex`, then modify column `id` and last remove `MultiIndex` by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

Also was added parameter names to `read_csv` for custom columns names.

```
Y = []
for x in S_Sub_list: 
    n = ['id', 'data', 'isEB', 'isEM']
    temp = pd.read_csv('sub' + str(x) +'_ICA_thre.csv', names = n)
    Y.append(temp)

#list comprehension alternative
#n = ['id', 'data', 'isEB', 'isEM']
#Y = [pd.read_csv('sub' + str(x) +'_ICA_thre.csv', names = n) for x in S_Sub_list]

df = pd.concat(Y, keys=range(1,len(S_Sub_list) + 1))

df['id'] = 'sub' + df.index.get_level_values(0).astype(str) +'_ICA_'+ df['id'].astype(str)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Thanks. It works, except the error from df['id'] = 'sub' + df.index.get_level_values(0).astype(str) +'_ICA_'+ df['id'] (cannot concatenate 'str' and 'long' objects)

Comment: It seems `id` column is not `string`s, so need `df['id'].astype(str)`

Comment: Thank you jerazel! It work, but when I need to load all files by removing keys in  df = pd.concat(Y, keys=range(1,15)), I got the values of the third and fourth column as float 0.0 and 1.0

Comment: Hmm, a bit complicated without your files, but it seems you need `df = pd.concat(Y, keys=range(1,len(S_Sub_list) + 1))`, because there is no only `14` files ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I used df['isEB'] = df.isEB.astype(int)

Comment: hi jezrael, it seems that the code rename all id based on the last int in the S_Sub_list.